# How does the squared residual of a high leverage sample observation differ from the population's variance?

Tags: regression, self-study, leverage

Is the high leverage sample observation considered a subset of the population, forcing its squared residual to be less than or equal to the population variance? Or am I misinterpreting the question? I'm trying to determine why the answer is false to the below question.

[image: Midterm Review Q]

Comment: Do you know what leverage measures, in an intuitive sense?

Comment: Yes, horizontal distance of an observation from the mean of the data. So is the answer that a high leverage point could have an squared residual of 0 which could be less than population  variance ?

Comment: "Distance from the mean" is not intuitively "leverage". Why is that called "*leverage*"?

Comment: That's how it was explained to me. Intuition is subjective.

Comment: Again, why *leverage*? What is this quantity designed to measure? Note the second paragraph on the Wikipedia page on [leverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_%28statistics%29)

Comment: Everything in that page says that leverage is the distance of the data from average predictor values, or extreme values of the independent variable, which is the same thing as being based on distance from the mean of the data. Not sure what you are driving at.

Comment: The second paragraph I pointed to is a single sentence. You surely cannot have missed the end of it: "... *means that the fitted regression model* ***will pass close*** *to that particular observation*". In particular, leverage is one measure of how hard each point *pulls the line toward itself*; observations with high leverage pull the line more strongly than low leverage ones, making their (squared) residuals smaller, on average (i.e. make the line 'pass close' to them).

Comment: So the statement is false as the correct answer is that the ith squared residual is less than or equal to the population variance?

Comment: Yes, your answer below to the question is correct (which is why I upvoted it a couple of hours ago); I was trying to convey why it was intuitively obvious that the answer is false without worrying about the exact formula. If one is clear on what leverage measures, the answer is apparent. Such time-saving strategies are important with true/false questions in a test situation, and additional intuition helps in other ways.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

and

[image]

Which precisely matches what I guessed initially, that any squared residual must be less than or equal to the population variance. These formulas also suggest that higher leverage will result in a lower squared residual.

Comment: This answer begins with a useful and relevant observation but then appears to conflate a "squared residual" with variance.  The two differ; a squared residual can be a lot larger than its variance even for influential data.

Comment: aren't squared residuals  an estimator for the population variance?

Comment: The estimator and the estimand are different things.  In this case we must clearly distinguish $e_i^2$ (the squared residual itself) from $\mathbb{E}(e_i^2)$ (its expectation--a population property) from $\sigma^2$ (another population property).

Comment: In that case what's the proper way to describe the answer using the above formulas?

Comment: My understanding is that $E (e_i)=0$ because the above analysis is (implicitly) conditioning on the configuration of the "X matrix".  So $E (e_i^2)=var (e_i) $ holds in this case.